# Fourier Output Meaning

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, fourier-transform

I just ran a fourier series on weekly sales data for 3 years worth of data.

I optimally chose the number of k-terms based on the AIC.

First 6 lines of my data:

```
sales_df<- ts(for_seasonality, freq=365.25/7, start=2015)
sales_df

Time Series:
Start = 2015 
End = 2018.64134154689 
Frequency = 52.1785714285714 
       sales_sum
  [1,]  16784338
  [2,]  15996710
  [3,]  16955621
  [4,]  17353905
  [5,]  19158498
  [6,]  20850803
```

Here is my function:

```
seasonality<-data.frame(fourier(sales_df, K=6))
```

Here are the first 6 lines of my output:

```
  S1.52     C1.52     S2.52     C2.52     S3.52      C3.52     S4.52      C4.52      S5.52      C5.52      S6.52      C6.52
1 0.1201262 0.9927586 0.2385126 0.9711394 0.3534447  0.9354554 0.4632579  0.8862235  0.5663619  0.8241566  0.6612635  0.7501537
2 0.2385126 0.9711394 0.4632579 0.8862235 0.6612635  0.7501537 0.8211001  0.5707842  0.9335419  0.3584683  0.9920985  0.1254612
3 0.3534447 0.9354554 0.6612635 0.7501537 0.8837203  0.4680153 0.9920985  0.1254612  0.9724076 -0.2332885  0.8271893 -0.5619233
4 0.4632579 0.8862235 0.8211001 0.5707842 0.9920985  0.1254612 0.9373419 -0.3484108  0.6692904 -0.7430009  0.2489398 -0.9685190
5 0.5663619 0.8241566 0.9335419 0.3584683 0.9724076 -0.2332885 0.6692904 -0.7430009  0.1307927 -0.9914097 -0.4537031 -0.8911529
6 0.6612635 0.7501537 0.9920985 0.1254612 0.8271893 -0.5619233 0.2489398 -0.9685190 -0.4537031 -0.8911529 -0.9296339 -0.3684844
```

I know I am supposed to add them together to get the "seasonality variable" for modelling. I am more interested in the meaning behind each of these columns.

If anyone has any insights or articles pertaining to this, it would be really helpful. Thanks!

I also tried this for the first value, and it doesn't match with the output.

[image]

[image]

This output is 0.541298 where the r-output is 0.1201.

Comment: Do you understand what is Fourier analysis decomposition? The reason I'm asking is because I never used this function before, but can guess what the output means by knowing what Fourier analysis is. So, if we know what you know about the subject, you'll get better help

Comment: I am fairly new to it but all I really know at this point is that it breaks down the data to extract the seasonality.

Comment: Perhaps best answered by the package author @RobHyndman.  I'll add the ```forecasting``` tag to get his attention.

Comment: See https://otexts.org/fpp2/useful-predictors.html#fourier-series

Comment: Thanks @RobHyndman. This was extremely helpful and it is making much more sense from your article. I attempted to manually calculate the first value with the sine function you provided. Am I not doing that part correctly? I included the formula in the question

Comment: $\sin\left(\frac{2\pi\times 1}{365.25/7}\right)= 0.12012616518235052$; $\sin\left(\frac{2\pi\times 2}{365.25/7}\right)=0.2385125751940.$

Comment: $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi\times 1}{365.25/7}\right)=0.9927586335250793$ ... $\sin\left(\frac{4\pi\times 1}{365.25/7}\right)=0.2385125751940764$...

Comment: It would seem that the "output" in your OP are the basis vectors and harmonics. Then you will actually need the coefficients `require(fpp2); tslm(sales ~ trend + fourier(sales_df, K=6))` or something along these lines, which will allow you to predict your actual sales values, such as `[1,]  16784338`.

Comment: Thanks! That's really interesting how that works. Regardless of the actual data, you will always get the same harmonics. It all really depends when you do an `auto.arima()` with the actual sales data to optimally choose the number of K-values. You can see which arima model produces the lowest AIC testing out each number of K-values. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just to confirm, if I wanted to extract the seasonality, do I just take the rowsums of my output I provided in the original question?

Comment: @AntoniParellada so in order to get the number of fourier terms, I used an arima model to obtain that. Whichever amount of K-terms produced the lowest AIC is what I went with. For the seasonality portion specifically though, would just the RowSum of my current output in the question work? - just for seasonality